# load font internally in magento

Tags: security, fonts, e-commerce, blocked

For security reasons, Browsers blocked any external unsecured links. In my case my website can not load some of Google fonts.

Can you guys advise how to load any customized fonts internally from my magneto theme?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load google fonts from both http and https like so

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Otherwise download the font and use them like so

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    src: url("../fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
}
```

Comment: That's a good answer. however I need to use another fonts, but I don't know where to upload them and how to call them into the website.

Comment: you download the font you want from google. then you upload it into your css folder and reference it from your css.

Comment: I got this font 'TheMixArab Regular', I have it upload into the font directory and used this syntax @font-face{font-family: 'TheMixArab Regular';
    src: url('../fonts/themixarab-regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}

Comment: ../fonts/ is a fonts folder one level up from the css. so if your foder strucure is correct then it should work

Comment: ../fonts/ located in the same level as css folder

Comment: Link is working, but internally is not working...what is the problem ?